# Julia push! or append! floating-point values onto an integer array

Tags: append, julia

I have an integer vector in Julia and want to push a floating-point value to it, or append a collection of floating-point value to it, but Julia throws an error when I try to do that:

```
julia> v = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> push!(v, 4.5)
ERROR: InexactError()
 in push! at array.jl:432

julia> append!(v, [4.5, 5.2, 3.1])
ERROR: InexactError()
 in copy! at abstractarray.jl:344
 in append! at array.jl:447
```

How can I add these values to this array?

Comment: Are you trying to add decimal places to your integers pairwise or append the decimal places at the end of the integer vector?

Comment: I've edited the question based on the assumption that @Gomiero's interpretation of the question is correct. If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't achive this with `append!`, since internally, `append!`
uses an `unsafe_copy!` and, as the documentation says:

> The unsafe prefix on this function indicates that no validation is performed on the pointers dest and src to ensure that
>    they are valid. Incorrect usage may corrupt or segfault your program, in the same manner as C.

It's possible to see this behavior in the following example, where, even with the
error message `InexactError`, the content of the `a` vector becomes invalid.

```
julia> a=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> append!(a,[3.14, 6.66, 1.61])
ERROR: InexactError()
 in copy! at abstractarray.jl:344
 in append! at array.jl:447

julia> a
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
                   1
                   2
                   3
 9223372036854775807
                  18
                  -1
```

The safiest way is to do a concatenation with `vcat` as follows:

```
julia> a=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a=vcat(a, [3.14, 6.66, 1.61])
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
 3.14
 6.66
 1.61
```

Or:

```
julia> a=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> a=[a; [dec(3), "6.66", "test"]]
6-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
  "3"
  "6.66"
  "test"
```

Note that after the concatenation, the array is promoted to a new type
(`Array{Float64,1}` and `Array{Any,1}`, respectively).

More information:

[Conversion and Promotion](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/)

[Arrays - vcat](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.vcat)